# PHP fopen fwrite removes indents and empty lines

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

**Background**

I've created a online code editor, using ACE (https://ace.c9.io/) and PHP (fopen and fwrite). On my local dev machine, the code i saved correctly to the file, with indents and empty lines, exactly as written in the editor. But on my live server, indents and empty lines are removed.

I'm really puzzled about this, since the code is the exact same!

**Example**

This:

```
<div>
    <div>

      // stuff here

    </div>
</div>
```

Will become this on my dev after save:

```
<div>
    <div>

      // stuff here

    </div>
</div>
```

And this on the live server:

```
<div>
<div>
// stuff here
</div>
</div>
```

**The Code**

The request comes from a javascript AJAX call, with the content from the ACE editor:

```
saveFile = function() {
    var contents = editor.getSession().getValue();
    $.post("/save",{filename: "{{ $filename }}", contents: contents },
        function(data) {
            // add error checking
            alert("Saved!");
        }
    );
};
```

Then sent to PHP:

```
$handle = fopen($file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$file);
fwrite($handle, $request->data('content'));
```

Any clue how the outcome on both server are not the same?

**EDIT**

After some more debugging, I've noticed that the files are stored correctly. So it must be when I read the file, and output it in the ACE editor.

I'm usin `file_get_contents()` to read the file. But I can't seem to find anything about it removing anything.

Comment: I wouldn't assume the issue is necessarily there.
Please check whether the data you receive in PHP is valid.

var_dump($request->data('content')) please and see all the indents are there.

After that I have some other theories (editor.getSession().getValue() can remove whitespaces, so can the PHP server with some input filters)

Comment: You're looking for the wrong culprit. `fwrite` does not modify its input. Verify the stored file, not the output. Else check up on the HTTP/AJAX request transmitting the right data. Lastly, figure out why the live server mangles the output. (Looks like HTML compacting stuff if whitepsace isn't preserved within `<div>` s)

Comment: `var_dump($request->data('content'))` shows that the indents are still there. The next line of code is the PHP handle. That is why I assumed it was there something went wrong.

Comment: Question edited. Files is stored correctly, so must be on read it fails.

Comment: whats the output of `var_dump( file_get_contents(...) )` ?

Comment: You said there are no spaces in the live server.
Are you sure?
Maybe it's the viewer you use there that doesn't show the spaces. Check if both files created are the same exact length( echo strlen(file_get_contents($filename)); )

Comment: if you cant find anything, encode your data (in case there is a html compression). You can use `JSON.stringify(...)` to encode and `JSON.parse(...)` to decode the data in JS. In PHP you use `json_[de|en]code`

Comment: `var_dump( file_get_contents(...) )` has the indents. So I tried doing json_encode($content) and then json_decode when echo'ing to the ACE editor. Didn't help. Still no indent on live.

Comment: well in this case i cant help any further without an working example